# Loop through inputs and get checked value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to get a list of radio inputs from a form that are grouped by their names, and they all have different names.  I'm trying to create an array with them, if they are checked then append a `1` to the array, otherwise append a `0`.  None of the alert boxes pop up, so I assume that the function `processDataForFinalization` doesn't get called.

I didn't know if something was wrong with how I'm appending to the array.  Or if it's a bigger error than that.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT4** Here is the updateBallot.php code

`TwoResults.txt` looks like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3 4 1 

<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$points = $_POST['points']; //array of user vote
echo $points;

$txt_file = file_get_contents($name.'Results.txt');

$rows = explode("\n", $txt_file); // rows-array separated by new line

foreach($rows as $row => $data) 
{
    $row_datas = explode(' ',$data);
}

$goods = $row_datas[0];
$goodies = $row_datas[1];

$newArr = [];
for($j=0;$j<count($points);$j++) {
    $newArr[$j] = $goods[$j] + $points[$j];
}

$newText = "";
foreach($newArr as $nArr => $nData) {
    $newText .= $nData." ";
}
$newText .= "\n";

$secondNewArr = [];

$sizeOfBottom = count($goodies);

for($k=0;$k<$sizeOfBottom;$k++) {
    $secondNewArr[$k] = $goodies[$k];
}

foreach($secondNewArr as $neArr => $neData) {
    $newText .= $neData." ";
}
$myFile = fopen($txt_file,"w+");
fwrite($myFile, $newText);
fclose($myFile);

?>
```

**EDIT3** Here is the output HTML from the page.

```
<form action="submitElection.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="20">
        <input type="hidden" name="numQs" id="numQs">
        <input type="hidden" name="arr" value="Array">

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("numQs");
            a.value = numQs;
        </script>

        <div id='ballotElement'><h4><u>q</u></h4>                  
        <input type="radio" name="input0" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                                  <input type="radio" name="input0" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                                  <input type="radio" name="input0" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                </div>                
                <script>
                  var numQs = 1;
                </script>
                <div id='ballotElement'><h4><u>q</u></h4>                        
                <input type="radio" name="input1" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                                  <input type="radio" name="input1" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                                  <input type="radio" name="input1" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                                  <input type="radio" name="input1" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                </div>                
                <script>
                  var numQs = 2;
                </script>
                <div id='ballotElement'><h4><u>q</u></h4>                  
                <input type="radio" name="input2" value="1">
                  a                  <br>
                </div>                
                <script>
                  var numQs = 3;
                </script>
                <br><br><br>      
             <div class="submit">
             <input type="submit" value="Submit ballot" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="return confirmSubmit()">
      </div>
        </form>
```

**EDIT2** Here is the HTML from the page.

```
<form action="submitElection.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="numQs" id="numQs">
        <input type="hidden" name="arr" value="<?php echo $arr;?>">

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("numQs");
            a.value = numQs;
        </script>

        <?php

        if (file_exists($name.'.txt')) {
          if($type==1) {
            $inputType = "checkbox";
          } else {
            $inputType = "radio";
          }

            $txt_file = file_get_contents($name.'.txt');
            $rows = explode("\n", $txt_file);
            array_shift($rows);

        $vals = 0;

            foreach($rows as $row => $data) 
            {
              $arrCount = 0; // number of elements in array
                echo "<div id='ballotElement'>";
                $row_data = explode('^',$data);

                $info[$row]['questions'] = $row_data[0];
                $info[$row]['answers'] = $row_data[1];

                echo "<h4><u>".$info[$row]['questions'] . "</u></h4>";
                //echo $info[$row]['answers'] . "<br>";

                $lines = explode("~",$info[$row]['answers']);
                foreach($lines as $line => $lData) { 

                $answers[$row][$line] = $lData;
                if($answers[$row][$line] !== "") {
                  $arrCount++;
                ?>
                  <input type="<?php echo $inputType; ?>" name="input<?php echo $row; ?>" value="1">
                  <?php echo $answers[$row][$line]; ?>
                  <br>
                <?php }
                  $vals++;
                }
              if($writeIn == "y") { 
              $arrCount++; ?>
                <input type="text" name="writeIn<?php echo $row; ?>" placeholder="Write in">
            <?php 
                }
                echo "</div>";
                array_push($arr, $arrCount);
                ?>

                <script>
                  var numQs = <?php echo count($arr); ?>;
                </script>
                <?php

              }
        } else {
          header('Location: error.php');
        }
            echo "<br><br><br>";

        <input type="submit" value="Submit ballot" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="return confirmSubmit()">
        </form>
```

**EDIT** getActualData() is called from getData()
Here is `getData()`, this function works, so I'm not sure why the `getActualData()` doesn't work since they are basically the same thing.

```
function getData() {


        var parts = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<numQs; i++){
          var checked = false;
          var inp = document.getElementsByName('input'+i);
          for(var j=0; j<inp.length && checked == false; j++){
            if(inp[j].checked) {
              checked = true;
              parts++;
            }
          }
        }
        if(parts != numQs){
          window.alert('Please vote for at least one candidate per race.');
          return false;
        } else {
          window.alert('Okay');
          getActualData();
          //return true;
        }

    }
  function processDataForFinalization() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'updateBallot.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {"points" : val, "name":name},
      success: function(data) {
        // Do something with data that came back. 
        window.alert(data);
        //return true;

      }
    });

  }

  var val = [];
  function getActualData() {

    for(var k=0;k<numQs;k++) {

      var inpu = document.getElementsByName('input'+k);
      for(var jk=0;jk<inpu.length;jk++) {

        window.alert('almost there');
        if(inpu[jk].checked) {
          window.alert('hello');
          val.array_push(1);
          window.alert(val.length);
        } else {
          val.array_push(0);

        }
      }
    }

   processDataForFinalization();

  }
```

Comment: it would be better you can show us your HTML also. Just looking at the javascript its hard to get what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm querying a database and displaying the radio buttons and inputs by echoing them out using php

Comment: echoing  them will be creating a markup right. You can at least show something similar to that so that we at least have an idea about the issue

Comment: If you want to send values of radio button than you can simply use  $( "form" ).serialize(); and send this in your ajax call data field. And handle the received data on your server script.

Comment: `.array_push()` should be `.push()` and `numQs` isn't defined in the code shown. Do you get errors in the browser's console? Where do you call `getActualData()` from?

Comment: I updated my answer with `getData()`

Comment: Throw an alert outside of the AJAX success call, and the first line of the function.  And also, you may want to switch from alerts to using `console.log()`, as you won't have to keep on clicking to close pop-ups, and it'll make debugging much nicer.  Just make sure to have the JavaScript console open (F12 in most browsers).

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried doing `.push()` instead of `.array_push()` and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Tim I also threw an alert outside of the AJAX and didn't get anything different.

Comment: @user3272438 Can you throw the HTML on the page too?

Comment: @Tim I added the html

Comment: @user3272438 Ah, can you go a bit further, and add the rendered HTML?  Like the actual DOM, instead of the PHP to generate it?  I want to throw it in a browser and mess with it.

Comment: .push() is correct, but from what you said in the question execution doesn't reach that line (which we know because you don't see the alerts before it). So, again, are you seeing any errors in the browser's dev console? If you have a syntax error or a runtime error it should appear in the console.

Comment: @Tim I have added the html output